# Azure B2C Xamarin Forms, clientId versus applicationId

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c

I followed this sample https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native to implement Azure B2C auth in Xamarin Forms.

There are two GUID in the sample

```
B2CConstants  ClientID = "e5737214-6372-472c-a85a-68e8fbe6cf3c";
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<data android:scheme="msale5737214-6372-472c-a85a-68e8fbe6cf3c"
```

and

```
MsalActivity.cs  DataScheme = "msal90c0fe63-bcf2-44d5-8fb7-b8bbc0b29dc6")]
```

Info.plist

```
<string>msal90c0fe63-bcf2-44d5-8fb7-b8bbc0b29dc6</string>
```

The first one is the clientId for the registered app in tenant, what about the second?

Some blogs called applicationId, so how can I get this from the Azure portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a **Custom Redirect URI**.You should make sure that your application has enabled the **Native client** setting and create it as shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

You could look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure-ad-b2c#android).

Comment: I would just like to point out that the redirect uri should not go into the iOS info.plist under CFBundleURLSchemes in the format it is presented in the Azure Portal. In all documentation it tells you to do this however the // characters will result in instant rejection when submitting builds to apple via app transporter. See the [example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/blob/master/UserDetailsClient/UserDetailsClient.iOS/Info.plist) for the correct method. This is a very big issue with the current microsoft docs!